# How can I get (or identify) multiple pieces of data sent by my RESTAPI?

Tags: java, php

I have created the following RESTAPI:

```
<?PHP

//connect to database, get coins player has, then define $coins
//also get the password hash ($hash)

echo json_encode([$coins, $hash]);

?>
```

Alright, so far so good.

Next my client (written in java) will read the response. I wrote some code to do that:

```
        try{
            URL url = new URL("http://example/rest.php");
            try{
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                connection.connect();

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        (connection.getInputStream())));

                String output;
                System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
                while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(output);
                }

                connection.disconnect();
            }
            catch(IOException e){
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
        catch(MalformedURLException e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
```

When printing the response, I get the coins and hash at the same time as a String. How can I identify the variables in java so I can actually use them? I would like to assign the data from `$coins to Integer coins = //get data` from the response, and vice versa with $hash.

Comment: Have a look at http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-to-jsonnode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you get valid JSON, you should use a JSON parser like Gson (https://github.com/google/gson) to parse the JSON you now read as a string into something meaningful.

The best way is to create some classes to hold your data, then have Gson map the recieved data to objects of those types.

There plenty of documentation and examples in the user guide. (https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md)

There are also other libraries for parsing JSON, so Gson is just an alternative.

On a sidenote I don't quite see how a password hash would be a valid second argument to the json_encode method, but that's not the problem here as far as I understand:)

Comment: Whoops, I wrote it wrong here, but on the server code it is actually an array 'json_encode('[$coins, $hash]'). Do not know why I did not think of this, thanks.

Comment: Yeah, figured it was just a typo or something since you said it worked. Anyways hope Gson or s similar library (Jackson is another alternative) helps you solve the problem:)